# django: Admin Ui: how to data dynamically into fileds based on selection option

Tags: django, dynamically-loaded-xap

I have django project, where in i have a drop down box and a multi-select list.
The data in multi-selected list should be populated based on selection from drop down box.

could some one help me here?

Answer (score 0):

Why dont u do this with javascript?

If i understand the problem correctly, below could be a solution:

1. Override the django admin page's base html.
2. Bind xxx function to ddbox's onchange event.You may use jquery(admin
   pages already use and include it) to get the ddbox dom object
3. In xxx function get ddbox, leftcolumn and right column dom objects
   with jquery.
4. Then do whatever u want.

Of course u may produce cleaner solutions.

Note : U can get the dom objects' id's easily with firebug or chromium debug toolbar